# Override Plugin Class Method - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I wish to override a plugin's class' method, only.

Say the method is called:

```
classMethod();
```

The class is in a third-party plugin. I don't want to change everything about the class, I just want to override the one method.

I don't want to write a new class to extend the plugin's class, because I would then have to go through the entire code of the plugin to make sure everything still works (I would probably need to change all references to the original class to my new class).

So, I am looking for a way to re-define classMethod(), only, in my theme's functions.php. Is this possible?

I.E. I don't want to create a new method. I want to re-define the classMethod() method and not change the method's name, so that all calls to classMethod() that currently exist, in the plugin, still work but now call my re-defined version.

Comment: [you may find answer here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/196026/how-do-i-replace-a-function-declared-inside-a-plugins-class-in-functions-php) Happy wordpressing ---------- BR